# Will using an NSKeyedArchiver/NSCoder persist even after an application update?

Tags: iphone, nskeyedarchiver, transcoding

I have NSKeyedArchiver and NSCoder data being persisted (as .txt files) and working great. When I deploy new builds to the iphone, the text files are still present - in other words, they are not being written over.

However, I want to make sure that the text files will persist when an itunes delivered update of my application is made available. I'm assuming yes, but just want to be sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all user data is persisted when your upgrade is delivered to a user by Apple. Indeed you need to make sure that you can upgrade from any state that the program could be exited in, which can complicate testing.

Comment: I only mention it because (according to an iTunes review at least) I didn't do just that :(